# How can I setup PRE_ACKNOWLEDGE mode using .NET Client application using AMQPNetLite

Tags: amqp, activemq-artemis

We are using a .NET Client using AMQPNetLite library to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis. I need to setup the pre-acknowledge mode and from the documentation, understood that this can be setup at the `connector` in `broker.xml` file. However, doing this didn't make any difference. It isn't very clear how to set this mode from [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/pre-acknowledge.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you cited is for ActiveMQ Artemis clients using the native "core" protocol. It doesn't apply to the AMQPNetLite client. That client is developed in [its own separate project](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite) which has its own [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/tree/master/docs/articles).

Also, for what it's worth, the documentation doesn't describe configuring pre-acknowledgement in `broker.xml`. It discusses configuring it on the client-side `jndi.properties` or programmatically via the JMS API. There is no way to configure pre-acknowledgement on the broker.

I recommend you take a look at "presettled" mode which is an AMQP semantic that should be essentially equivalent to pre-acknowdgement in ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: I probably have mistated that the pre-acknowledgement flag could be configured in broker.xml file but this is something that I was hoping I could do. I'm trying to achieve preacknowledgement of  messages for the setup I have with a .NET Client connecting to Artemis Active MQ using AMQPNetLite library. Any pointers on this can be very helpful. TIA

Answer (score 1):

In terms of AMQP clients the idea of PRE-ACKNOWLEDGE mode would amount to creating the AMQP receiver link with the `snd-settle-mode` in the Attach frame to `SETTLED` so that the remote is informed that it should send your receiver deliveries that are already settled indicating the client wouldn't need to respond with a settled disposition itself as the remote has said it has already forgotten about the delivery.

As that relates to the AMQPNetLite you would be creating a ReceiverLink and giving it a custom defined Attach object with the settlement mode configuration you want which would like something like the below although you will need to test and tweak as needed.

```
Attach attach = new Attach();
attach.SndSettleMode = SndSettleMode.SETTLED;
attach.RcvSettleMode = RcvSettleMode.FIRST;

ReceiverLink receiver = new ReceiverLink(session, address, attach, onAttached);
```

Information about [link establishment](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/os/amqp-core-transport-v1.0-os.html#doc-idp315568) and Attach options can be found in the AMQP 1.0 specification.